# Undelete link doesn't work after inline editing an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, undelete, inline-editor

When inline editing a deleted answer, after saving the updated answer the "undelete" link does not work. To undelete the answer the page needs to be reloaded and then it works properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, also for flagging and closing links, which suffered from the same issue.