# Cannot Use "Close" or "Flag" after inline edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, inline-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undelete link doesn't work after inline editing an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98310/undelete-link-doesnt-work-after-inline-editing-an-answer)

I just inline-edited a question on SO and realized there was a vote to close. Wanting to see what reason had been given, I clicked it, and nothing happened. I also clicked Flag, and nothing happened either.

Using Firefox 5.0, no messages in the Error Console on clicking either link. The Link link (er...) works fine, and editing again works too.

Add-on: It's also not necessary to actually edit the question. Just enter inline editing and save.