# Cannot vote to close immediately after edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, vote-to-close

If I edit a question and then click the "close" link, it doesn't work. Nothing appears on the screen and I'm forced to reload the page before the link works.

A [related meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98310/undelete-link-doesnt-work-after-inline-editing-an-answer) covers similar ground (except my edit wasn't inline), however this was apparently fixed.

(I've tagged as [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) as this is the only site I have the reputation to reproduce the issue on.)

Comment: Yep, noticed the same thing.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186246/205508

Comment: @Johnツ Damnit, had a good hunt before I posted :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

This has been fixed and will be in the next build.

Comment: That was swift - this was already a known issue?

Comment: @DuncanJones - Yes. Fixed and reverted yesterday (after the fix broke other things...).

Comment: Then you can tag/answer/close my question as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185886/142802.